# jquery search custom

Tags: jquery, css, input, search

See this site http://g1.globo.com/ has a custom search field that uses jquery for any of the bottom also if placed a value in less than 2 appears a custom alert.

I am hours here trying to find a solution to copy me and I can not, I am totally a layman and not getting to.

If a friend i know and can get me the code I am grateful.

I thank,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

and check out the minLength attribute

Comment: No friend, this is not, note the code there to see, I'd like something in that style.

Comment: You mean visual style? That part will be up to you no matter which path you choose. Though speaking of which, did you play with the theme-roller? It's pretty bad-ass